# processingを用いてのボロノイ図を作成するプログラムの作成

Tags: processing

今現在、processingを用いて、ボロノイ図を作るプログラムを作成してします。

プログラムの内容としては、任意の位置に６つの点を配置し、それから成るボロノイ図を表示するというものです。

ボロノイ図は、各点の垂直二等分線を引き、その交点からボロノイ図が成ると認識しています。

プログラムとしては、各点の垂直二等分線を引き、その交点までは求められました。
しかし、その交点からボロノイ図を作成することができません。

どのようなアルゴリズムで作成すればいいでしょうか。

Comment: @user30682 さん、スタック・オーバーフローでは質問文下の「編集」から自由に追記することができます。新しく編集された質問は質問一覧で上に表示され、回答者の目に触れることになるのでご安心ください。同じ内容のご質問は同じ投稿にまとめてくださると回答の手間が減って助かります。まとめて頂けるとありがたいです。

Comment: また、動かなくて良いので、現在のソースコードを追記してくださいませんか？　その方が適切なアドバイスができます。